# How can I work with a slice of a table thru power query?

Tags: group-by, powerbi, powerquery

I am trying to add a new column ("% variation") to my table in which I am trying to divide the monthly numbers in the table below by the December (12) for a given year. The idea is to show the variation in the monthly numbers vs the final number (December = 12). For example I want the first row column in % variation to have **0.9934 (=10.63/10.7 i.e. val for 1-2010/ val for 12-2010)**, second row to have 1.0065 (=10.77/10.7) the 12th row where the value will be 1 (10.7/10.7). For the 13th row since a new marketing year has started, the value in the 13th row should be 1.0222 (= 9.67/9.46 i.e. val for 1-2011/ val for 12-2011) so on and so forth.

[image]

I can do this in python with a single line of code below

`df_monthly_changes ['% Variation'] = df_monthly_changes.groupby('Marketing_year Index').Val.apply(lambda x: x/x.iloc[-1])`

but I am stuck on how to replicate this in power query (power BI).

Comment: If you're using PowerBI, then this kind of calculation is best done in the data model with DAX.

Comment: Yes I am using PowerBI. But not able to come up with a logic to divide each month of a particular year by December value of the same year to show the evolution of val over time for each year.

Comment: Do you have a calendar dimension in your data model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In M Code in Power Query, you can

- Group by the year
- Add a column to each group using a custom aggregation to divide each entry by the last entry

  - You could add some logic if not all years have 12 months
- Re-expand the resulting table.

***M Code***

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table30"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Marketing_year", Int64.Type}, {"Marketing_month", Int64.Type}, {"Val", type number}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Marketing_year"}, {
        {"Var", (t)=> Table.FromColumns(
            Table.ToColumns(t) & {List.Transform(t[Val], each _/t[Val]{11})},
                {"Marketing_year","Marketing_month", "Val", "Variation"}
    )}}),
    #"Expanded Var" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Var", {"Marketing_month", "Val", "Variation"}, {"Marketing_month", "Val", "Variation"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Var",{{"Marketing_month", Int64.Type}, {"Val", type number}, {"Variation", type number}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Ron. This is exactly wht I ws looking. As u have rightly pointed out there are some years which don't have twelve months so I used List.Last(t[Data]) to capture the last value (data was already sorted by month).
Also if you don't mind could you please explain what does this do **{"Var", (t)=>** in the code line below 
`#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Marketing_year"}, {
        {"Var", (t)=> Table.FromColumns(
            Table.ToColumns(t) & {List.Transform(t[Val], each _/t[Val]{11})},
                {"Marketing_year","Marketing_month", "Val", "Variation"}`

Comment: @Neeraj `Var` is the name of the new column; `(t)=>` captures the sub-table produced by the `Table.Group` function so that variable can be used in the subsequent formula.